# Is there a plugin that integrates to CPPUnit with VS2008 or Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, eclipse, unit-testing, user-interface

We have some projects that have CPPUnit tests that are build and run using an ant script to build them all (right now we're using Borland C++, but we're moving to VS2008).

The problem is that the interface to run and see the result of tests is unpleasant (command prompt). It would be awesome to have them run inside eclipse or VS2008.

It would be a lot better if a plugin that I could select the tests I want to run and get some visual feedback (green bar/red bar), pointing me to the tests that failed and the messages.

This exists with JUnit in Eclipse (for java), but is there something similar for C++ using Eclipse CDT or VS2008? A UI test runner would be usefull too, so I could launch the UI as a Post build action.

**EDIT (possible answer):**

I found this project: [ECUT](http://sourceforge.net/project/screenshots.php?group_id=236439), however I didn't test it yet. Looks promising thou. I'll update this question as soon as I get more experience with the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their doesn't seem to be a test runner for within Visual Studio, just the [MfcTestRunner](http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=MfcTestRunner) and the [QtTestRunner](http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=QtTestRunner).

For Visual Studio, [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and [TestDriven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/) are the usual suspects to first look for test runners, but both don't have support for CPPUnit.

Answer (score 1):

I found your post in my quest for a simple CppUnit integration with Eclipse CDT, so for everyone like me who is seeking a simple CppUnit integration with Eclipse CDT:

I have created an Eclipse plugin to support vanilla CppUnit XML Test Reports with the official Eclipse CDT C/C++ Unit Testing Support plugin.

I have made it available on [GitHub](https://github.com/jmrharris/eclipse.cppunit.testsrunner)

So **yes**, now there is :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a GUI test runner that comes with cppunit, you could use that in your post build event.

Answer (score 0):

> cxxunit is another solution for test
>   framework.

http://web-cat.cs.vt.edu/eclipse/cxxtest/